# Multiple entities in schema.org

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

How do I nest one or multiple recipes in a `NewsArticle` or `BlogPosting`.

I tried this but [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) throws an error complaining about `recipe1` key. I'm not sure what to change `recipe1` key to:

```
  <script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "NewsArticle",
  "author" : { "@type" : "Person",
      "name" : "hgezim"
    },
  "dateModified" : "2016-09-21T06:25:35+00:00",
  "datePublished" : "2016-09-21T06:25:35+00:00",
  "headline" : "Chicken Papriak",
  "mainEntityOfPage" : "http://localhost:8080/2016/09/21/chicken-papriak/",
  "publisher" : { "@type" : "Organization",
      "name" : "Dev Blog"
  },
  "recipe1": {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Recipe",
    "author": "John Smith",
    "cookTime": "PT1H",
    "datePublished": "2009-05-08",
    "description": "This classic banana bread recipe comes from my mom -- the walnuts add a nice texture and flavor to the banana bread.",
    "image": "bananabread.jpg",
    "recipeIngredient": [
      "3 or 4 ripe bananas, smashed",
      "1 egg",
      "3/4 cup of sugar"
    ],
    "interactionStatistic": {
      "@type": "InteractionCounter",
      "interactionType": "http://schema.org/Comment",
      "userInteractionCount": "140"
    },
    "name": "Mom's World Famous Banana Bread",
    "nutrition": {
      "@type": "NutritionInformation",
      "calories": "240 calories",
      "fatContent": "9 grams fat"
    },
    "prepTime": "PT15M",
    "recipeInstructions": "Preheat the oven to 350 degrees. Mix in the ingredients in a bowl. Add the flour last. Pour the mixture into a loaf pan and bake for one hour.",
    "recipeYield": "1 loaf",
    "suitableForDiet": "http://schema.org/LowFatDiet"
  }
}
  </script>
```

Comment: What do you want to convey? What would be the purpose of `BlogPosting` inside a `NewsArticle`? For quoting? And what would be the purpose of `Recipe` inside `NewsArticle`? Is it the main content of the article? But in that case, is it really a `NewsArticle`?

Comment: Let's say I want a `Recipe` (or more) inside a `BlogPosting`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the entities are related to each other. You have to use a property that is defined to convey this relation.

To look for a suitable property, check [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) for properties that have [`Recipe`](http://schema.org/Recipe) or one of its parent types ([`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork), [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing)) as expected value.

For example:

- [`about`](http://schema.org/about) could be used if the blog post is about this specific recipe (e.g., you describe how you liked it)
- [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart) could be used if the recipe forms a part of the blog post
- [`mentions`](http://schema.org/mentions) could be used if you just reference this recipe in the blog post
- …

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @unor. I've used `hasPart` as follows:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{ "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "NewsArticle",
  "author" : { "@type" : "Person",
      "name" : "hgezim"
    },
  "dateModified" : "2016-09-21T06:25:35+00:00",
  "datePublished" : "2016-09-21T06:25:35+00:00",
  "hasPart" : { "@context" : "http://schema.org",
      "@type" : "Recipe",
      "author" : "John Smith",
      "cookTime" : "PT1H",
      "datePublished" : "2009-05-08",
      "description" : "This classic banana bread recipe comes from my mom -- the walnuts add a nice texture and flavor to the banana bread.",
      "image" : "bananabread.jpg",
      "interactionStatistic" : { "@type" : "InteractionCounter",
          "interactionType" : "http://schema.org/Comment",
          "userInteractionCount" : "140"
        },
      "name" : "Mom's World Famous Banana Bread",
      "nutrition" : { "@type" : "NutritionInformation",
          "calories" : "240 calories",
          "fatContent" : "9 grams fat"
        },
      "prepTime" : "PT15M",
      "recipeIngredient" : [ "3 or 4 ripe bananas, smashed",
          "1 egg",
          "3/4 cup of sugar"
        ],
      "recipeInstructions" : "Preheat the oven to 350 degrees. Mix in the ingredients in a bowl. Add the flour last. Pour the mixture into a loaf pan and bake for one hour.",
      "recipeYield" : "1 loaf",
      "suitableForDiet" : "http://schema.org/LowFatDiet"
    },
  "headline" : "Chicken Papriak",
  "mainEntityOfPage" : "http://localhost:8080/2016/09/21/chicken-papriak/",
  "publisher" : { "@type" : "Organization",
      "name" : "Dev Blog"
    }
}
</script>
```

It validates as [validates JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-expanded&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22NewsArticle%22%2C%22author%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22Person%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22hgezim%22%7D%2C%22dateModified%22%3A%222016-09-21T06%3A25%3A35%2B00%3A00%22%2C%22datePublished%22%3A%222016-09-21T06%3A25%3A35%2B00%3A00%22%2C%22hasPart%22%3A%7B%22%40context%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22Recipe%22%2C%22author%22%3A%22John%20Smith%22%2C%22cookTime%22%3A%22PT1H%22%2C%22datePublished%22%3A%222009-05-08%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22This%20classic%20banana%20bread%20recipe%20comes%20from%20my%20mom%20--%20the%20walnuts%20add%20a%20nice%20texture%20and%20flavor%20to%20the%20banana%20bread.%22%2C%22image%22%3A%22bananabread.jpg%22%2C%22interactionStatistic%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22InteractionCounter%22%2C%22interactionType%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FComment%22%2C%22userInteractionCount%22%3A%22140%22%7D%2C%22name%22%3A%22Mom's%20World%20Famous%20Banana%20Bread%22%2C%22nutrition%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22NutritionInformation%22%2C%22calories%22%3A%22240%20calories%22%2C%22fatContent%22%3A%229%20grams%20fat%22%7D%2C%22prepTime%22%3A%22PT15M%22%2C%22recipeIngredient%22%3A%5B%223%20or%204%20ripe%20bananas%2C%20smashed%22%2C%221%20egg%22%2C%223%2F4%20cup%20of%20sugar%22%5D%2C%22recipeInstructions%22%3A%22Preheat%20the%20oven%20to%20350%20degrees.%20Mix%20in%20the%20ingredients%20in%20a%20bowl.%20Add%20the%20flour%20last.%20Pour%20the%20mixture%20into%20a%20loaf%20pan%20and%20bake%20for%20one%20hour.%22%2C%22recipeYield%22%3A%221%20loaf%22%2C%22suitableForDiet%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FLowFatDiet%22%7D%2C%22headline%22%3A%22Chicken%20Papriak%22%2C%22mainEntityOfPage%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F2016%2F09%2F21%2Fchicken-papriak%2F%22%2C%22publisher%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22Organization%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Dev%20Blog%22%7D%7D).